# Target specific element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown that changes the text value of a span based on what the user has selected in the dropdown. **Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/ebstcrjy/

Right now, my code targets the *next* span it sees.

I would like to target a specific span based on the class `startdate`.

How do I modify my code to target this particular element?

```
$(function() {         
    $('#usertype').change(function() {        
        $(this).next("span").text($('#usertype option:selected').text());
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery uses css selectors:

```
$('.startdate').text($('#usertype option:selected').text());
```

Comment: Many thanks, Dimitri L. - worked perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/ebstcrjy/2/

Comment: @michaelmcgurk ; This changes all of the `'.startdate'` elements in page. If you want to affect only next one this is not true.

Comment: I'm cool with it changing that. I'll perhaps target by `#startdate` instead. Thank you for your constructive comment :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {         
    $('#usertype').change(function() {        
        $(this).siblings("span.startdate").text($('#usertype option:selected').text());
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [css class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) in jQuery. Based on your markup, you only have one element that uses the `startDate` class. If you wanted to get more specific, you could assign that element an id and then use the id selector.

```
  $(function() {         
        $('#usertype').change(function() {        
            $(".startdate").text($('#usertype option:selected').text());
        });     
    });
```

From the docs:

> **jQuery( ".class" ) class:**
>
> A class to search for. An element can have
> multiple classes; only one of them must match.

---

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/rcccg2aj/).

Comment: but `.startDate` is a span how to confirm?

Comment: This won't work, .next() only looks at the first sibling..

Comment: @l.varga updated. Just a copy and paste error :-)

Comment: @Jai, there is no need to confirm it since only one of the elements in your markup has the class. Follow the link that I provided to the docs to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

This will change only the `.startdate` span that is after the changing select element:

```js
$(function() {         
        $('#usertype').change(function() {        
            $(this).siblings('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '~span.startdate').text($('#usertype option:selected').text());
        });     
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" id="myhidden3" name="quantity" value="1" />
  <span class="startdate">first span</span>
  <select id='usertype'>
    <option value='1'>Start Date</option>
    <option value='2'>End Date</option>
    <option value='3'>End Date</option>
  </select>
  <span>Hello!</span>
  <span class="startdate">Start Date</span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

just select the span by type and class like so

```
$("span.startDate").text($('#usertype option:selected').text());
```